# Learndash: import/export all courses/topics/lessons with database or plugin

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, phpmyadmin

I'm using Learndash plugin on my Wordpress website.

I have many courses (around 100) and more topics (around 2000).

I want to export all the courses from my website to import them into another website.
So I decided to search on the web some plugins to do it and I found wppluginforyou but it has 2 different plugins to do this. Then I thought about copy database informations (but I don't know how to do it).

Can you help me to copy data from my database to paste it to my other website's database ?
Plus, can you tell me if you know any plugins 2 in 1 (Import and Export) to do this more "safely" ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

there is plugin for learndash where you can use excel to import courses
the plugin called

Excel to Learndash Course Import

From wppluginsforyou

Might want to check it out